# Calling `.lock()` on weak_ptr returns NULL shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14, weak-ptr

I am somewhat confused by the behaviour of the `.lock()` call on a `weak_ptr`.  My understanding is that `.lock()` will return a `shared_ptr` of the relevant type if it has not expired *otherwise* it will be a null pointer.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock :

> A shared_ptr which shares ownership of the owned object if std::weak_ptr::expired returns false.

This is however not the outcome I am seeing.  The code below is a method of the `Unit` class that should return a `shared_ptr` to the `Unit`'s parent:

```cpp
unsigned Unit::getParentId() const {
    auto parent = parent_.lock();
    return parent->getId();
}
```

The debugger output below shows that `parent_` exists as a `weak_ptr`.  However when I call `auto parent = parent_.lock();`, it returns a `NULL` pointer as can be seen in the last line of the debugger output.

I am obviously missing something really basic here?

```cpp
this = {const Unit *} 0x16f1af010 
 id_ = {unsigned int} 234
 name_ = {std::string} "Test"
 parent_ = {std::weak_ptr<Unit>} std::__1::weak_ptr<Unit>::element_type @ 0x00006000034d00d8 strong=0 weak=2
  __ptr_ = {std::weak_ptr<Unit>::element_type *} 0x6000034d00d8 
   id_ = {unsigned int} 0
   name_ = {std::string} "Root"
   parent_ = {std::weak_ptr<Unit>} nullptr
   children_ = {std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>} size=0
 children_ = {std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>>} size=0
parent = {std::shared_ptr<Unit>} nullptr
 __ptr_ = {std::shared_ptr<Unit>::element_type *} NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak pointer attaches only to existing shared pointers, by itself weak pointer doesn't hold or create any object pointer. In other words if you do:

```cpp
std::weak_ptr<int> wp;
auto sp = wp.lock();
```

then it always returns nullptr. You have to pass Existing shared pointer in constructor or through assignment (`=`), e.g.

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<int> sp = std::make_shared<int>();
std::weak_ptr<int> wp(sp);
auto spl = wp.lock(); // now spl is not null
```

or through assignment

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<int> sp = std::make_shared<int>();
std::weak_ptr<int> wp;
wp = sp;
auto spl = wp.lock(); // now spl is not null
```

As long as all copies of shared pointer still exist then weak pointer will return non null on lock. Otherwise if no copies of shared pointer exist then weak pointer will always return null.

In your case you don't have any copies of shared pointers hence weak pointer will alway return null on lock in such case.

Comment: Thanks @Arty, and the `shared_ptr` must be in the same scope I assume.

Comment: @Paul At least one copy of shared pointer must be alive. That's all what's needed. If you assigned (or passed through constructor) shared pointer to weak pointer then shared pointer may go out of scope as long if it wasn't the only copy. So shared pointer doesn't need to be in scope, you may have a heap copy of shared pointer somewhere.

Comment: Actually, thought I was doing this with the following method.  Clearly this is not correct though```void Unit::setParent(shared_ptr<Unit> parent_ptr) {
    parent_ = parent_ptr;
    parent_.lock()->addChild(make_shared<Unit>(*this));
}```

Comment: @Paul I think last copy of your shared pointer was destroyed somewhere. Even if weak pointer holds a reference to shared pointer still only copies of shared pointers matter. If last shared pointer was destroyed then all weak pointers will hold NULL.

Comment: @Paul All shared pointers pointing to same object form a kind of "cluster". Weak pointer is just a reference to some EXISTING cluster. Weak pointer doesn't manage any pointer itself. If cluster of shared pointers die (all destructed or went out of scope) then all weak pointers that referenced this cluster will now give NULL when locked. For weak pointer to return non-null on lock at least one shared pointer inside a cluster must be still alive. If in your program all shared pointers die then you should use shared pointers instead of weak everywhere. Shared ptr is very light, use it everywhere.